# Add image based on option tag value

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to put an image based on the option tag value?

For example,

```
<option value="1">USA Flag</option>
```

would return the file name ''1'' from **/flags** directory. (e.g: mysite.com/flags/1.png)

Comment: Onchange, you read the value, build a string, set an image's src. seems easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try something like this?

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
var value = input.value;
var image = "mysite.com/flags/" + value + ".png";
```